# Unable to open two (so far) SSL sites, all others work normally

Tags: windows, ssl, time

I have tried IE, Chrome, and FF. I have turned off WiFi on my mobile device and the connection goes through normally. From my computers connected to my internet, I'm unable to load the pages, it just times out. When I ping the SSL subdomain it times out, tracert shows it making to their edge network and then it times out. I've confirmed no problems with the site or service I'm trying to access.

I have restarted my modem and router, reset the modem, changed my DNS servers to Google's and I'm having the same issue. I don't know what else could be going on, all other SSL sites work and when I view the companies main page it loads but going to their secure sites like sign in, time out.

Comment: IE and Chrome use a different certificate store then Firefox.  Have you placed the certficate in the certificate store for the user and also added it to the Firefox certiicate store?

Comment: @Ramhound, The certificate already existed for FF and my user. All we is FF, just tested on Chrome and IE to see if it was a browser issue.

Comment: Since you are able to connect through your mobile carrier's network and (I assume) not through your WiFi on your mobile device, I would suspect it was an issue with your land-based internet connection. What does Chrome report as the error when it fails to connect?

Comment: @OranD.Lord, that is my suspicion but don't know where to go from here. My ISP has confirmed they can access it and that it might be an IP issue, I contacted the company and confirmed that I'm on no sort of block list of any type. 

All browsers just display a page cannot be displayed, connection timed out error.

Comment: One possibility is if you have a firewall configured to redirect port 443 for some reason, the responses might be getting dropped on the way back to you.

Comment: @OranD.Lord, I turned off my Windows firewall to test and same thing. I've made no changes to my modem/router security stuff and these sites were working normally about 2-3 days ago.

Comment: @Jamie If it's a laptop, you should take it to work or a library to rule out the internet provider. Have you had success connecting to other HTTPS sites?